# Extrapolate a row by quantity in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been wondering how to solve the following problem. Say I have a dataframe `df`, which looks like this:

```
Name     quantity     price
A        1            10.0
A        3            26.0
B        1            15.0
B        3            30.0
...
```

Now, say I wanted to extrapolate the price by quantity, and for each `Name` create a row for `quantity = 1,2,3`, which is some function of the list of available quantities and respective prices. (I.e. say that I have a function `extrapolate(qts, prices, n)` that computes a price for `quantity=n` based on known `qts` and `prices`, then the result would look like:

```
Name     quantity     price
A        1            10.0
A        2            extrapolate([1, 3], [10.0, 26.0], 2)
A        3            26.0
B        1            15.0
B        2            extrapolate([1, 3], [15.0, 30.0], 2)
B        3            30.0
...
```

I would appreciate some insight on how to achieve this, or a place to reference to learn more about how `groupby` can be used for this case

Thank you in advance

Comment: What if there is 1 followed by 4? How is 2 and 3 calculated then?

Comment: Let's say that `extrapolate` knows how do compute itself with arguments `qts=[1,4], prices=..., n=2,3`

Comment: sound like combination of  , groupby+reindex +fillna

Comment: I edited my solution below, please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want is called missing **data imputation**. There are many approaches to it.

You may want to check package called [fancyimpute](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fancyimpute). It offers imputing data using [MICE](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3074241/), which seems to do what you want.

---

Other than that, if your case is just as simple in structure as the example is, you can always `groupby('Name').mean()` and you will get the middle value for each subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do what you described:

```
def get_extrapolate_val(group, qts, prices, n):

    # do your actual calculations here; now it returns just a dummy value
    some_value = (group[qts] * group[prices]).sum() / n

    return some_value

# some definitions
n = 2
quan_col = 'quantity'
price_col = 'price'
```

First we group by `Name` and then `apply` the function `get_extrapolate_val` to each group whereby we pass the additional column names and `n` as arguments. As this returns a series object, we need an additional `reset_index` and `rename` which will make the concatenation easier.

```
new_stuff = df.groupby('Name').apply(get_extrapolate_val, quan_col, price_col, n).reset_index().rename(columns={0: price_col})
```

Add `n` as additional column

```
new_stuff[quan_col] = n
```

We `concatenate` the two dataframes and are done

```
final_df = pd.concat([df, new_stuff]).sort_values(['Name', quan_col]).reset_index(drop=True)

  Name  price  quantity
0    A   10.0         1
1    A   44.0         2
2    A   26.0         3
3    B   15.0         1
4    B   52.5         2
5    B   30.0         3
```

The values I now added in are of course meaningless but are just there to illustrate the method.

**OLD version**

Assuming that there is always only `1` and `3` in your `quantity` column, the following should work:

```
new_stuff = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False)['price'].mean()
```

This gives

```
  Name  price
0    A   18.0
1    B   22.5
```

That - as written - assumes that it is always only `1` and `3`, so we can simply calculate the `mean`.

Then we add the `2`

```
new_stuff['quantity'] = 2
```

and `concatenate` the two dataframes with an additional sorting

```
pd.concat([df, new_stuff]).sort_values(['Name', 'quantity']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

which gives the desired outcome

```
  Name  price  quantity
0    A   10.0         1
1    A   18.0         2
2    A   26.0         3
3    B   15.0         1
4    B   22.5         2
5    B   30.0         3
```

There are probably far more elegant ways to do this though...